# How to change UIButton text

Tags: uibutton, tvos

When writing apps for iOS you can simply change the text of a `UIButton` by writing:

```
variable.text = ("")
```

However, with tvOS you cannot write `.text` and I was wondering if anyone knew how you could do it.

Comment: So are you talking about TVML?

Answer (score 3):

To change the text/title of a `UIButton` you need to use `setTitle:forState:`.

Objective C:

```c
[myButton setTitle:@"A New Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Swift:

```c
myButton.setTitle("A New Title", forState: .Normal)
```

**[UIButton Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:)**